# Excel as a data capture tool in the field

Tags: excel, vba

The new role I have taken on is with a company who are very dependent on excel, and who have hundreds of field based engineers who use spreadsheets as their sole method of communication. Inspections are carried out, results are recorded on a macro-fuelled template, which is them emailed to head office (usually as a pdf – the template has the capability to export to this format). 
The contents are them are manually entered onto another spreadsheet that acts as a sort of master overview. This ‘master overview’ is them emailed out to several Area Managers who complete an ‘Action’ field and email the ‘master overview’ back to head office.
Of course, by this time there are several copies of the ‘master overview’ flying about that them need to be consolidated onto one file and de-duped if necessary. This is in addition to the manual step at the start of data entering from a pdf (which originally was in excel before exporting and emailing).
This is a great pity because the template really has some clever stuff on it that ultimately does not get captured from the data entry stage.
I have been tasked with streamlining this laborious and repetitive process, and I am looking for some inspiration, or some established strategies from businesses who undertake similar activity. 
I am not a software developer (I’m thinking some sort of app should be developed), and I think I am pretty much stuck (for now) with excel 2010 and elbow grease.
Does anyone have a flash of brilliance, or a method that I can research? Or, are we realistically looking at developing something more fit for purpose?
Thanks in advance for your help – much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why a PDf format ? Can they email the spreadsheet as an excel attachment, then write a script to transfer the information ?

I have to do something similar each morning for reports. Everyone else here enters the info manually. I use a rudimentary script that does a basic copy and paste routine between 2 different spreadsheets. I'm sure some "real" programmers could give you something much better, but currently the following script works for me.
Hope this helps.

```
Sub ImportAll()
'
' ImportAll Macro
' Import data from other worksheets
'
 Dim myPath2
 myPath2 = Workbooks("driver_daily_sced_load_count_kilgore.xlsm").Sheets("MAIN").Range("S12").Value  

Range("AA1").Value = 1
Range("AB1").Value = 1
'   Get rejected loads from the CSV file
 Windows("driver_daily_sced_load_count_kilgore.xlsm").Activate
  Sheets("CSV").Select
   Range("J12:J15").Select
    Selection.Copy
'   Paste rejects in the current Load Count report
  Windows(myPath2).Activate
   Range("B29").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,         SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'   Get Load data from the CSV report
  Windows("driver_daily_sced_load_count_kilgore.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("CSV").Select
      Range("B12:H15").Select
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
'   Paste load data in the current Load count report
   Windows(myPath2).Activate
    Range("B10").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
'   Get drivers data from from daily count
  Windows("driver_daily_sced_load_count_kilgore.xlsm").Activate
   Sheets("MAIN").Select
    Range("AY23:BC26").Select
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Selection.Copy
'   Paste driver data in the current Load Count report
  Windows(myPath2).Activate
   Range("P29").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'   Get OUT OF TOWN drivers data from from daily count
  Windows("driver_daily_sced_load_count_kilgore.xlsm").Activate
   Sheets("MAIN").Select
    Range("BG23:BG26").Select
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Selection.Copy
'   Paste driver data in the current Load Count report
  Windows(myPath2).Activate
   Range("W29").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'Range("W31").Value = 2 'this is used on occasional basis

'Get Morning Report Data (NOT LOAD COUNT)
   Range("B21:W21").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Selection.Copy
 Windows("driver_daily_sced_load_count_kilgore.xlsm").Activate
  Sheets("MAIN").Select
   Range("R18").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Windows(myPath2).Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("B24:Z24").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: I guess it's just habit - that's always the way it's been done. But I like the idea of keeping it in excel and transferring the information. The problem is, the template looks like it contains some pretty advance VBA, but I cannot access the VBE project as it is protected.

Comment: Does your proposal involve having the 'user interface' of the file save the data on a hidden tab using VBA, then, once the excel file arrives, we could write a VBA script to extract the data from the hidden tab and append it to a master file? I need to do two things - unlock the VBA in the worksheet to modify the file to store the data on a back tab, and write the script. Any suggestions about where I could start researching such a script? I do have some basic VBA, but this is straying into unchartered territory for me! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @James Neil, sorry, I didn't see this until today..ugh ! I use a "template" file (spreadsheet) that I put information from 2 spreadsheets that are exported from a web page report, and a CSV file (text). I then use the info gathered to put into 4 other seperate spreadsheets. I know it sounds cumbersome, and it took me a long time to get it right, but all in all, I can do the whole process in 10 minutes, vs the 45 minutes it took by hand. At least using your own sheet to gather the data gives you control.